# Using a straight end FPC connector for a tapered end FPC

Tags: connector, fpc, ffc

I am new to working with FFC/FPC, and had a question about the different types of ends for these cables.

I have a piezomotor that connects via a 1mm pitch tapered end FPC. I need to connect this to a PCB in a very tight area. The recommended connector is [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0522710669/3262877?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKxjAdgIwAYBsGCcIC6AvkA) Molex 522710669 connector, but for my purposes this connector is too long (13mm) and I will need contacts on the top instead of the bottom. The other tapered end connectors I have found are all similar lengths and will not fit.

However, I have found a connector that is small enough to fit my use, a [TE 84981-6](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/84981-6/2272406). The only issue is that this is a connector for a straight end FPC, and my cable has a tapered end. Is this an issue? To my mind, using a tapered end FPC in a straight connector shouldn't be a problem, since it shouldn't play a major role in alignment. Is there another reason why this may not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tapered FPC tail in an FFC socket that can accept a non-tapered FCC is not a problem.